# Neo4j Java API - support for specifying batch size

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Is there any way to mention the transaction batch size while defining the Transactions. At present we are kind of managing with a raw counter variable. Kind of closing & re-creating the transaction once batch size reached.

Please advise if there ways to specify the batch size and neo4j internally manages the transaction commit over multiple batch size.

We know this is possible by cipher, but I am more interested to know about the Java way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Java land you control the transaction size on your own. E.g. neo4j apoc project provides some code doing exactly see https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/master/src/main/java/apoc/periodic/Periodic.java#L244-L258.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, this implementation looks great.. We would try this definitely